# CMake find_package can't find libpng (16)

Tags: windows, cmake, msbuild, libpng

I'm not the first to run into `libpng` issues, especially when I want to link to self-built sources on Windows. I'm using the `libpng1638` sources from [https://github.com/glennrp/libpng](https://github.com/glennrp/libpn). Semi official - the reason for this version is it has a `CMake` build/install script.

zlib is built/found and the library installs in `c:\Program Files\libpng` (I  have set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` for this)

The problem occurs when doing a `find_package(PNG 16)`. With debug flag on, a number of search directories is listed, but ultimately it fails to find the `PNG-config.cmake` script that can link up to the installed paths and files.

It doesn't seem to help when I set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the correct folder, and the reason is explained below.

This the command I used in the script (`zlib` is already found):

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE TRUE)
find_package(PNG 16         PATHS "C:\\Program Files\\libpng\\lib\\libpng")
set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE FALSE)
```

This is the output of the debug trace:

```
...
find_package considered the following locations for the Config module:
  ...
  C:/Program Files/CMake/PNGConfig.cmake
  C:/Program Files/CMake/png-config.cmake
  C:/Program Files (x86)/PNGConfig.cmake
  C:/Program Files (x86)/png-config.cmake
  C:/Program Files/libpng/lib/libpng/PNGConfig.cmake
  C:/Program Files/libpng/lib/libpng/png-config.cmake
```

Indeed, no `png-config.cmake` file can be found anywhere on my system. In the source `CMakeLists.txt` of `libpng`, the section to create these `XXX-config.cmake` scripts has been deliberately disabled for `Win_32` systems:

```
  # Install the pkg-config files.
  if(NOT CMAKE_HOST_WIN32 OR CYGWIN OR MINGW)
    install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libpng.pc
            DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/pkgconfig)
    install(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libpng-config
            DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
    install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PNGLIB_NAME}.pc
            DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/pkgconfig)
    install(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PNGLIB_NAME}-config
            DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
  endif()
```

Since I don't want to dabble in the source files (which ultimately are pulled from the web directly), I want to understand. Why would this be disabled for native Win32 builds? (most of the online info uses the Linux subsystem or a package manager.. )

Other packages like `zlib` have their `XXX-config.cmake` files properly copied to the install folders where `FindXXX.cmake` scripts can pick them up properly.

For completeness, here is the output of the `libpng` build (msvc)

```
  -- Install configuration: "Debug"
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/lib/libpng16d.lib
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/bin/libpng16d.dll
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/lib/libpng16_staticd.lib
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/include/png.h
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/include/pngconf.h
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/include/pnglibconf.h
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/include/libpng16/png.h
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/include/libpng16/pngconf.h
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/include/libpng16/pnglibconf.h
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/bin/pngfix.exe
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/bin/png-fix-itxt.exe
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/share/man/man3/libpng.3
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/share/man/man3/libpngpf.3
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/share/man/man5/png.5
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/lib/libpng/libpng16.cmake
  -- Installing: C:/Program Files/libpng/lib/libpng/libpng16-debug.cmake
```

All insight greatly appreciated!

**Update 1**

After fiddling with the install commands, I have to conclude that libpng-`libpng16.zip` from https://github.com/glennrp/libpng is not maintained with  Windows as build target in mind.

`lpng1637.zip` from https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/ has the same problem.

**Update2 :**

So far I have tried setting `PNG_DIR`, setting the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and a number of other things that failed. Just one seems to work, which is setting the environment `PNG_ROOT` variable to the correct installation folder. This is dead ugly, but it seems to be the only option that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for people who, like me, are trying to use `freetype2` in a Windows project, here's how to build the dependencies:

- make sure your `zlib` is built and installed also in the `C:\Program Files\Zlib` folder
- `zlib` can usually be found without issues. To be sure, remove all other occurrences especially those under `C:\Program Files (x86)` if you have them. This will make sure `find_package(..)` cannot confuse between the different targets. Use `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to force building/installing into that directory.
- set the environment PNG_ROOT environment variable to `C:\Program Files\libpng`
- set the environment BZIP2_ROOT environment variable to `C:\Program Files\bzip2`
- set the environment ZLIB_ROOT environment variable to `C:\Program Files\zlib`

I did the same for dependencies `Brotli` and `Harfbuzz`, but no luck so far. `Harfbuzz` seems to have some strange chicken/egg relationship to freetype2.

For setting up the build for `freetype2` with `CMake`, after building the dependencies, these flags work:

```
-DFT_DISABLE_HARFBUZZ=True 
-DFT_REQUIRE_PNG=True 
-DFT_DISABLE_BROTLI=True 
-DFT_REQUIRE_BZIP2=True 
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Program Files\libpng;C:\Program Files\bzip2;C:\Program Files\brotli;C:\Program Files\zlib;C:\Program Files\harfbuzz"
```

Note that `libpng` pulls in `zlib` as dependency, so there's no real need to specify that flag imho, so I'm not touching it.